# sed/awk - remove all tags except only two tags and plain texts

Tags: text-editor, sed, awk

here is a sample for my text file:

```
<w:r><w:t>
<w:r w:rsidR="00D171FD">
<w:t></w:t>
</w:r><w:r>
<w:t xml:space="preserve">
This is a sample text </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:highlight w:val="green"/>
<w:r w:rsidR="00D171FD">
<w:color w:val="FF0000"/>
<w:t>
Sample text</w:t>
</w:r>
```

The problem is that I need both the **pure text** and the following **tags** only: 
`color w:val="FF0000"`
`highlight w:val="green"`

How can this be done?

Comment: Could you post your expected output from sed or awk? You might be better of with a xml parser for this, see e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64708/8677

Comment: I think I'm gonna make a script to do it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the above command line it will function if you will never have those expression as text:

1. `<w:`
2. `\>`

The command line is:

```
cat Myfile.txt  | grep -E "color w:val=|highlight w:val=" | sed s/"<w:"/""/g | sed s/"\/>"/""/g
```

Explanation:

- `grep  -E, --extended-regexp PATTERN`
  Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression
- `|` logical OR inside the PATTERN of `grep`
- `|` pipe symbol in shell environment
- `sed s/"<w:"/""/g` substitutes globally (everywhere) `"<w:"` with empty string `""`

Note: it's possible to write `sed` in many other way and in a more compact way. I think so is *didactic* and can be used in a more wide range of possibility when is needed to substitute an expression with another.

This is the output:

```
highlight w:val="green"  
color w:val="FF0000"
```